# My TailWind CSS Intellisense plugin just isn't working on my VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

So the description of the plugin is that it'll display suggestions of classes when am working on the markup, but it doesn't. I've reloaded the plugin countless times. I even restarted vscode and eventually re-installed it.
Of course, I did the `npm install tailwind` and other utilities needed... I even have my `tailwind.config.js` file in my project if that helps to answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: I'm also new to tailwind, but it is working for me. Are you pointing to a compiled version of `tailwind.css` in your html file? For me it's about 1MB.

Comment: No, I don't think I've been working with that file. How do I get it?

Comment: Watch this video: https://tailwindcss.com/course/setting-up-tailwind-and-postcss/

Comment: For me, I added the `syler.sass-indented` extension, and then Tailwind IntelliSense started working for me.

Comment: On my side reopening project helped.

Comment: Anyone stumbling over the same issue of tailwind completion not happening in .erb files, see [Tailwind CSS autocomplete in VSCode with Ruby on Rails](https://medium.com/@spaquet/tailwind-css-autocomplete-in-vscode-with-ruby-on-rails-63a5fc24a1a4). It was the key for me.

Answer (score 142):

Its actually a pretty simple fix. open your `settings.json` file then add this to get the `intellisense` working on all files

```js
"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "html": "html",
    "javascript": "javascript",
    "css": "css"
},
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "strings": true
}
```

Comment: This has helped me after searching for answers for hours.

Comment: This is the solution! Should be accepted answer! It gives you hinted description of the css which is added by each class too.

Comment: The only thing needed to get autosuggestions to work was:   "editor.quickSuggestions": { "strings": true } not sure why you include the other stuff?

Comment: This solution works for me!  I was creating a new VS Code profile but it turns out that this config is missing in my setting.json.

Comment: This also worked for me, although my project didn't have any settings.json file, so created one. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me instead of the accepted answer. The accepted answer might be a prerequisite, but that alone didn't do it for me.

Comment: This no longer works (at least for me)

Answer (score 107):

I'm using tailwindcss in a react app. Tailwindcss Intellisense plugin was not working in my VSCode but then i installed `HTML CSS Support extension` and now i am getting suggestions of classes.

[HTML CSS Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css)

[image]

Comment: May I ask if anyone knows why this works? 

(Yes, it worked for me too. Thank you @Ahmad!)

Comment: I had to upgrade vscode version first, then this worked.

Comment: it worked though I had uninstall and reinstall this HTML CSS Support plugin. Odd.

Answer (score 61):

**To fix this issue try using `ctrl + space`**

This is the easiest way I found to get Tailwind IntelliSense to work with .js files to React. You need to do this every time you are adding a new class but it's quicker than checking the documentation every time.

[Credit: Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/dsisfd/anybody_experienced_problems_with_vs_code_and/)

Comment: How to do this in macbook?

Comment: This shortcut is occupied on Macs by default. You can free it up by navigating to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Input Sources and removing both check boxes

Answer (score 58):

What helped me was to check whether the plugin had any issue loading. You can do this by checking the output view:

- `CTRL + SHIFT + P` to bring up the command palette
- Search for "Output: Focus on Output View"
  [image]
- In the Output View, search for `tailwindcss-intellisense`
  [image]

For me the error was
`Failed to initialise: ReferenceError: defaultTheme is not defined` -  I was missing a `require` for the [defaultTheme](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#referencing-the-default-theme).

Comment: I searched tailwind intellisense in extention, then I found Tailwind CSS IntelliSense (bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss), so I installed that. Thanks to this thread!

Comment: Thank you, I had my output hidden, this showed me to my issue.

Comment: THIS! Thank you. I deleted the last script in package.json and didn't remove the trailing comma. oops.

Comment: Answers like this one really upgrade you. It helps you debug the problem and help solving the problem in your own ways. In my case, I have to install [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#install-tailwind-via-npm)tailwindcss via npm. I was using tailwindcss directly with npx and it looks like intellisense extension require npm install.

Comment: Yes works, usually it isn't if something broke in packages. Thanks

Comment: I also searched tailwind intellisense and that gave me an error message that I needed VS Code version above ~1.52 to run it and I apparently had ~1.50. This led me to update VS Code. And it worked.

Comment: YES! This might be my problem! I got "The language client requires VS Code version ^1.67.0 but received version 1.66.1"... Let me give it a shot now and see

Comment: Not the first time I get a problem with Tailwindcss intellisense and not the first time this answer helped me. I wish I could update multiple times!

Comment: Thanks for this! I ended up having an errant character in my package.json file that was causing tailwind to fail to load.

Answer (score 12):

for me..

I installed 'IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML', 'HTML CSS Support', 'CSS Peek' all together with reinstalling..

It works now.

Comment: I did this, but didn't reinstall or reload. It worked!

Comment: This one worked for me (using CRA and Typescript), I have no idea why

Answer (score 11):

To anyone still facing this problem, I found that the tailwind extension doesn't recognize your `tailwind.config.js` file if it's untracked (not added to source control). Once I added the file and did `git commit`, the extension worked.

Comment: For quick tests, I usually use the CDN version, so I don't really need the `tailwind.config.js`, but it seems the extension doesn't work without it.

Comment: Weirdly, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 11):

if you're using nuxt/tailwind module be sure to init `tailwind.config.js` as doc says.

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

then restart the vs-code. it should automatically be active.

Comment: This one was helpful for my case.

Answer (score 11):

Edit your VSCode settings.json:

```
"files.associations": {
  "*.css": "tailwindcss"
},
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "strings": true
}
```

Sometimes is needed to restart vscode.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using **tailwind + create-react-app + typescript**, I solved it by changing the extension setting `"Tailwind CSS: Include Languages"`, to `{"plaintext": "ts"}`.

I don't know why it didn't work in the first place, it was working for my other projects.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this work for me (tailwind, cra, typescript); to restart vscode use cntrl + shift + p > Developer: Reload Windows

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to get it working with JSP files. I had to go to this setting and add item: jsp, value: html. Then it sprang into life.

Answer (score 8):

Just go to the
`Tailwind CSS IntelliSense`
extension in `Vs code`
and install the old version and reload it.
It works.
[image]

Comment: For the older version ,toggle the uninstall option and choose the 2nd option. ( I installed  version 0.7.5)

Comment: yes is working, but can you tell me why the newer version doesn't work anymore? thanks for the answer

Answer (score 6):

For React project with `.tsx` file, adding this works for me.

```json
// .vscode/settings.json

{
  "tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "typescriptreact": "html"
  }
}
```

Credit: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense/issues/72#issuecomment-674386396

Answer (score 3):

I am using **Tailwindcss** with **Django**.
Facing the same issue where **Tailwindcss IntelliSense** plugin is already installed and autocomplete wasn't working.

Finally I got the perfect solution.

For most projects (and to take advantage of Tailwind’s customization features), you’ll want to install Tailwind and its peer-dependencies via npm.

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

In my case the postcss and autoprefixer was not installed.
You can run the above command and npm will take care of it if you have Tailwindcss already installed.

Also don't forget to put these lines in your **settings.json** in VSCode (Recommended VS Code Settings for Tailwind CSS IntelliSense):

```
// VS Code has built-in CSS validation which may display errors when using Tailwind-specific syntax, such as @apply. You can disable this with the css.validate setting

"css.validate": false,

// By default VS Code will not trigger completions when editing "string" content, for example within JSX attribute values. Updating the editor.quickSuggestions setting may improve your experience:

"editor.quickSuggestions": {
     "strings": true
},

// This setting allows you to add additional language support. The key of each entry is the new language ID and the value is any one of the extensions built-in languages, depending on how you want the new language to be treated (e.g. html, css, or javascript):
    
"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
     "plaintext": "django-html"
},
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution for autosuggestion on typing. So you don't need to use space+ctrl or just space. In case anyone needs it.

```
editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions: false
```

Answer (score 2):

Without pressing `ctrl-space`, I just need to press `space` and the classes will come out.

Answer (score 2):

### This setting is good working for react.js application

```
{
    "tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
        "class:\\s*\"([^\"]*)\""
    ],
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true,
   
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "strings": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Did did the trick for me in my Next.js project!

Answer (score 2):

I disabled and re-enabled the plugin. Wait a bit for it to re-indexing. And it works.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by creating a tailwind.config.js file with the help of `npx tailwindcss init` command. I was following tutorials of net ninja (youtube channel) and he mentioned this solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tailwind with react, typescript, javascript, styled-components, and twin-macro, you have to add classRegEx manually to get the IntelliSense

To achieve this edit the user settings as below

```
 "tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
    "tw`([^`]*)",
    ["classnames\\(([^)]*)\\)", "'([^']*)'"]
  ],
```

For more information and to see what classRegEx should use with other techs  [read this](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense/issues/129)

Answer (score 1):

At first, write in your project `npm install tailwindcss postcss-cli autoprefixer`, Then write in your terminal `npx tailwind init`, at last write `npm tailwind"postcss.config.js` and then write in the file:

```
module.export = { plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')]};
```

last step u can build your `tailwindcss` in `packagein` accordance with the `package.json`.

For more info u can visited this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21HuwjmuS7A&list=PL7CcGwsqRpSM3w9BT_21tUU8JN2SnyckR&index=2).

Comment: works for the react projects

Answer (score 1):

Running `Tailwind CSS: Show Output` from `View -> Command Palette` (or *Ctrl + Shift + P*), as suggested [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense#troubleshooting), unveils that the "Tailwind CSS IntelliSense" plugin is looking for a proper *npm installation* of the module `tailwindcss`.

**Solution:** We can therefore fix the issue by simply running

> `npm install tailwindcss`

within our project directory.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you open the project from its root folder. I happened to me that there were multiple package.json files in the a different folder, the VS code plugin will be confused with tailwindcss path.

Just open the Explorer view and you should see one and only one package.json file and tailwindcss is listed as the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

### How to get it working with denoland's `Fresh` framework

Check that the extension is not loading by opening the `OUTPUT` tab of the console and verifying that the dropdown menu has an entry for `Tailwind CSS IntelliSense`.

**If it does not figure there you need to make a blank `tailwind.config.js` file at the root directory.**
This file is completely redundant with Deno, but required by the extension.

---

If it still does not help, try other methods shown in this thread. With the extension loading latest version of it does work on with setup.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Troubleshooting section of https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense:

> Make sure your VS Code settings aren’t causing your Tailwind config
> file to be hidden/ignored, for example via the files.exclude or
> files.watcherExclude settings.

This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried most of the solution but what worked for me is this , just copy past the following , you can remove the iconthem if you want .

```
{
    "tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
        "html": "html",
        "javascript": "javascript",
        "css": "css"
    },
    "css.validate": false,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "file-icons-mac",
    "tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "strings": true
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me helps installed plugin **IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML**

Comment: Please adda link to the extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion

Answer (score 0):

#### Rails erb - Custom class name completion contexts

Add to settings (ctrl + shift + p)

```
"tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
        "class:\\s*\"([^\"]*)\""
]
```

[See github issue reply](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense/issues/129#issuecomment-764760030)

Answer (score 0):

I did Smit @Barmase solution but also added "plaintext" and "tsx".

Now everything works when I hit space after previous class.

Answer (score 0):

*hi,*

I have the solution

first: 
     download tailwindcss from node.js or (npm) 
second:
     write in your project terminal in vscode
     `npx tailwindcss init`
     to will create `tailwind.config.js`
and download the tailwind css 
 intellisense plugin for vscode
**and working!**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the code completion not working without the start tag `>`.

Not work:

```
<div class=""
```

Work:

```
<div class="">
```

### My best practice

Strictly speaking, it doesn't work without the start tag `>`. But My best practice is to write the closing tag and then write the class.

First write:

```
<div class=""></div>
```

Second write:

```
<div class="w-10"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem only by deleting the space between the equal sign and and quote.
So instead of writing `className= "tailwind classes..."`  write `className="tailwind classes..."`. I hope that this answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update VS Code

I had the same issue I just fixed it by **updating VS Code**.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Intellisense, the *output* in VSCode for the "TailWind CSS IntelliSense" had

```
[Error - 1:36:36 PM] Tailwind CSS: Cannot set property 'parent' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'parent' of undefined
```

This seemed to be coming from the `postcss-nested` plugin, however after reading a few other SO posts on the similar issue it actually came down to my setup.

The main project folder was failing to parse a file that existed inside a sub-project (td;lr. using a wordpress theme git repo that is build with the template as the root).

Since the original setup to process the TailWind wasn't needed, I noticed that the root project was TailWind v3, while the sub-project was TailWind v2.  After removing the base `package.json` dependancies Intellisense kicked in picked up the [sub-project] tailwind config, postcss and tailwind version.

Not sure if that might be similar to your setup, but what is suggested is checking the package versions, and that your tailwind config files (if any) are setup right.

The moment you fix it, you should immediately be able to see in the *Output* tab for "TailWind CSS IntelliSense" something similar to the following....

```
Found Tailwind CSS config file: /.../tailwind.config.js
Loaded postcss v8.3.0: /.../node_modules/postcss
Loaded tailwindcss v2.2.0: /..../node_modules/tailwindcss
```

Hope there's something you can take away from this.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The extension `HTML CSS Support extension` is not the correct way to go. As specified in the official installation section of the detail page in the extension page in VSC.

> In order for the extension to activate you must have tailwindcss installed and a Tailwind config file named tailwind.config.js or tailwind.config.cjs in your workspace.

so adding a file (even empty) named `tailwind.config.js` or `tailwind.config.cjs` at the root of your app will make it work.

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration

Comment: In order for the extension to activate you must have tailwindcss installed and a Tailwind config file named tailwind.config.{js,cjs,mjs,ts} in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with the tailwind.config.js. Since I followed the Tailwind installation step by step, I put the content as

```
content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"]
```

While I had no src folder, rather my html file was at the root. So I changed it to below and the IntelliSense started working.

```
content: ["/*.{html,js}"]
```

So just in case someone is making this silly mistake like me :)

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed a new VSCode version and also unistalled and installed again Tailwind CSS IntelliSense extension, and it just started working!

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, switching to another file that uses CSS and then switching back answered the question.

It might take some time before it starts working after launching VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Windows Subsystem for Linux you might be getting an error similar to:

> Tailwind CSS: Can't resolve //wsl$/foo/tailwind.config.js

Installing the [WSL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) should fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. In my case I have a structure like this:

```
- Root
-- Client
-- Server
```

I'm using typescript within `Client` but I hadn't set `compilerOptions.baseUrl` in `tsconfig.json`;

After setting `baseUrl` to `./` in `tsconfig.json`, I magically started getting intellisense.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are solving a typescript problem, while the question is about intellisense

Comment: Just sharing what worked for me in my use-case of having 2 different projects within the same directory whilst NOT being a mono repo – which is why I shared the context in which this worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your vscode extensions if tailwind was enabled.

Due to some settings on my vscode i realised tailwind intellisence was disabled. Had to enabled it and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a project with **multiple** `tailwind.config.js` files, TailwindCSS Intellisense will only load the first one it finds.

Unfortunately there is no solution yet ([issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense/issues/218)).

---

In my  case, I have two projects with a `tailwind.config.js` in a monorepo.

Thus a workaround is to open only the project I am currently working on.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the Extensions view and then search for Tailwind CSS, make sure it is Enabled. Mine was installed but not enabled and that is why it was not working.