# Tailwindcss Intellisense not working in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, vscode-tasks, tailwind-3

I have checked out many answers from Stack Overflow but I wasn't able to fix the issue that IntelliSense not working for Tailwindcss. But vscode Intellisense working for other things like python and javascript. Please anybody help me why this isn't working. I am using Tailwindcss Cli. even CSS file Intellisense also not working.

my config file is. `tailwind.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I also added this setting into `.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
"css.validate": false,
"liveServer.settings.port": 5501,
"tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true,
"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
  "plaintext": "html",
  "javascript":"javascript"  
},
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": true,
    "strings": true
},
"tailwindCSS.classAttributes": [
    "class",
    "className",
    "ngClass"
]}
```

#### once a thing. CSS compiled successfully but Intellisense not working. and this is my project folder structure. please anybody help me, please.

[image: folder structure of project]

Comment: Try restarting VS Code, and if it doesn't work then remove and re-install the Tailwind CSS VS Code extension. At least that worked for me.

Comment: yeah... sure.. but I checked those things before posting this question... thank you soo much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you almost got it... i added this to my settings and it worked.
what you are missing (in my opinion) is "inlineSuggest" - full snippet here:

```json
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
   "strings": true
},
"css.validate": false,
"editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true
```

Comment: This is the answer

Comment: nope this isn't the answer i already set this one long time ago

Answer (score 4):

I found that intellisense for the extension will not work with single quotes. I had my ESLint config set to `"jsx-quotes": ["warn", "prefer-single"]`. If I use double quotes in my `classNames`, the intellisense works fine.

The solution for me was to update my `settings.json` to include `"editor.quickSuggestions": { "strings": true }`

Answer (score 3):

My case was because I haven't updated my VSCode version. I knew the trouble because I checked on the Output Log > Tailwind CSS IntelliSense. You might need to check the log as well because the trouble can vary.

Here is the screenshoot of the output:
[image]

Comment: So I can learn from this. What about this output helped you come to that conclusion?

Answer (score 2):

In my case because I changed my user's name file in the past so VS Code has error 5 with auto-update. When I fix that error and updated lasted version, it work

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the Tailwind CSS IntelliSense [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss)?

[image: VS Code extension]

Comment: yeah... I have installed this extension...

Comment: also not working IntelliSense for any library like react...

Comment: Does IntelliSense work for anything at all?

Comment: yes.. intellisense work for other things such as for python, for javascript, for CSS property name. but not working for Tailwindcss..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My TailWind CSS Intellisense plugin just isn't working on my VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61343447/my-tailwind-css-intellisense-plugin-just-isnt-working-on-my-vscode)

Answer (score 1):

After trying every solution out there, the only thing that worked for me was to install the previous version of Tailwind CSS IntelliSense extension.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the name of the parent folder.

I structure my folders like this: `D:\[1] git` and inside I have all the projects.

For some reason tailwind intellisense wouldn't initialize, even after I did everything already suggested.

But when I changed the parent folder to `D:\git` it worked.

So deleting the `[1]` from the path seemed to do the trick.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed the extension and had no luck with other answers, invalidate cache/remove node modules and yarn/npm your project again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you still can not fix this problem:

1. Uninstall Tailwind CSS Intellisense from your VSCode and close it
2. Go to where your local vscode exntensions are stored, mine is "C:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions"
3. Check if there're any folders called **bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss**, if yes then delete all of those
4. Now, re-open your VSCode and install Tailwind CSS Intellisense once again