# tailwind not suggeting class after plugin install (intellisense not working ,@tailwindcss/line-clamp )

Tags: tailwind-css

I installed the plugin `@tailwindcss/line-clamp`, but its not working its not being suggested by intellisense  and even when I type in the class manually it doesn't change my styling .
here is my tailwind config :

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.tsx', './src/**/*.ts'],
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('@tailwindcss/line-clamp')],
}
```

btw this a typescript React project .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This same thing happend with me as well. For me I was using tailwind alongside with daisyUI and sometimes the vscode pulgin was working sometimes not.

1. One thing you can follow, make sure to use the tailwind docs [Taiwind Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) and follow the instruction on how to install tailwind for your project as per the framework you are using. Give it a try.
2. Or if it's not working you can try installing the below extention along side with tailwind extention in vscode.

   [HTML CSS Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css)
3. You can also try to add the below in your `settings.json`. It worked for me actally.

```js
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "strings": true
}
```

For more on this one - [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61343447/my-tailwind-css-intellisense-plugin-just-isnt-working-on-my-vscode)

Comment: thanks the intelesence is not working still ,  but the plugin does its job finally .

Answer (score 0):

answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72731657/12763140

The extension `HTML CSS Support extension` is not the correct way to go.you should follow the official installation section of the detail page in the extension page in VSC.

> In order for the extension to activate you must have tailwindcss installed and a Tailwind config file named tailwind.config.js or tailwind.config.cjs in your workspace.

so adding a file (even empty) named `tailwind.config.js` or `tailwind.config.cjs` at the root of your app will make it work.

Comment: Please don't repeat-post the same answer to different questions.